# I am trying to assign a variable a value using Elvis Operator inside of an each loop but true values are evaluating to false and vice versa

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to map peoples GitHub accounts with their Slack names so I can send a notification via Jenkins to that person but true values are evaluating to false and vice versa when I use the Elvis operator

(Note: The test_user variable is a representation of the username I will be trying to map to a Slack user):

```
def USERS_MAP = [    
  'johnny': [
      git: 'japple',
      slack: 'johnny.apple'
  ],
  'Sam': [
      git: 'ssmith',
      slack: 'sam.smith'
  ],
  'Terrance': [
      git: 'tkeller',
      slack: 'terrance.keller'
  ],
  'Billy': [
      git: 'brogers',
      slack: 'billy.rogers'
  ]
]

def test_user = 'brogers'


def slack_name


USERS_MAP.each{ k, v -> (  (v.git == test_user)  ?: (slack_name = v.slack) ) }

println slack_name
```

This is the output I receive for slack_name:

```
terrance.keller
```

I expected to receive "billy.rogers" as his GitHub account is the only one that should have matched the test_user in the Elvis operator's boolean portion.

What really strikes me as odd is if I change the "==" to a "!=" it works fine:

```
USERS_MAP.each{ k, v -> (  (v.git != test_user)  ?: (slack_name = v.slack) ) }
```

Output for slack_name:

```
billy.rogers
```

Can anyone explain what is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not 100% sure why your code is doing that but perhaps a better way of getting what you want is

```
def slack_name = USERS_MAP.find { k, v -> v.git == test_user } ?.value?.slack
```

Comment: That definitely works. Thank you. I see you are iterating over all the USER_MAP to find where test_user is equal to a USER_MAP record. But would you mind explaining what is happening when you call "?.value?.slack"

Comment: Find will return the first entry that matches (as opposed to findAll which returns a list of all matches). When find doesn't find a match if will return null. The ?. is a null safe call. This essentially saying "find the first match and return the slack id for it, but return null if nothing found"

Answer (score 1):

The Elvis operator is behaving correctly - it specifically assigns a value when the test is false. You seem to want it to assign a value when the test is true, but that's not how it works.

The Elvis operator is basically just the normal ternary assignment operator with the first result expression removed - instead of:

```
result = test ? value_when_true : value_when_false
```

it's just:

```
result = test ?: value_when_false
```

It's normally used for setting a default value when a variable is missing:

```
result = possibly_missing ?: 'default value'
```

If `possibly_missing` evaluates to Groovy `false`, the expression evaluates to `"default value"`, otherwise it evaluates to the value of `possibly_missing`.

https://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/08/groovy-goodness-elvis-operator.html

Comment: I should add that, as Michael Rutherford says in his answer, the Elvis operator isn't the right thing to use at all, his example is far more appropriate. Your code has an assignment expression in the Elvis operator, which is valid code but pretty much an anti-pattern, like the classic `if (x = 1) { ... } `.